# How to close fragment correctly?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Now I have a fragment to do something will last long time. In some case , the activity will call `onSaveInstanceState` when fragment is still running. After fragment do all the things , I want to close it. Here will throw an exception `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`.

I know what it means, but I really need to close the fragment after something has been done. So if I use `commitAllowingStateLoss` to force fragment to close , after activity recreate, the `close state` won't be recreated, the UI will be broken.

So how should I close the fragment correctly ?

Comment: Could you please specify which kind of work are you doing in your fragment?

Comment: @dkarmazi like downloading or others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any safe way to automatically close fragment, and it seems like a bad idea (why would you depend on the system for this?). You will have to time it correctly in your app. I can give you code suggestion to do it. Since there is no close method, you use `remove` method instead, or `popBackStack`. Since you did not post any code, I am suggesting a generic way to do this.

Code suggestion using remove:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
...
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.remove(fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Notes:

- TAG_FRAGMENT is the ID for the fragment in the layout.
- findFragmentByTag() is one way, another is new myFragment();
- If you need to time when the Fragment is closed, use **onDetach**() override method of Fragment.

Comment: Also use onDetach of Fragment if need to time when the fragment closes.

Comment: I know the `FragmentTransaction` but my question is how to commit such remove function when `onSaveInstanceState` has been called. `commitAllowingStateLoss` can force to do `remove` function but it won't let `State` to save this `remove state`.

Comment: @zzy, First you did not say explicitly the reason for overriding onSaveInstanceState (). Yes, your fragment may still be running even before that method. But what is the real problem with that? If your fragment needs to pass data to the Activity, then you can pass data in onDetach() of Fragment. I mentioned that in my post.

Comment: @zzy, Perhaps you need to find code for passing data from Fragment to Activity. Would you want to solve it that way?

Comment: The data is stored to another place and how to pass data doesn't matter.`onSaveInstanceState`is called by system not me, the problem is when system call `onSaveInstanceState`, I `can't remove` fragment now if I want it is `still removed` after activity `recreated`.

Comment: @zzy, If I understand you right and I m trying, you don't need to close/remove the fragment. Perhaps you don't need to override onSaveInstanceState. I don't normally. Most UI states are saved by the framework until app closes.

Comment: I think so , if I need rewrite the code , I won't use fragment to do this . just inflate view will be much easier to me .